# Exception in UIMA while loading analysis Engine

Tags: java, uima

I get an Exception when i try to load Analysis Engine via CAS Visual Debugger or Document Analyzer GUI in UIMA.
The exception is:

```
org.apache.resourceInitializationException EXCEPTION MESSAGE LOCALIZATION FAILED: java.lang.NullPointerException
caused by: org.apache.resource.ResourceConfigurationException EXCEPTION MESSAGE LOCALIZATION FAILED: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

P.S- I am new to UIMA.

The full stack trace is :
org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException: EXCEPTION MESSAGE LOCALIZATION FAILED: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.uima.resource.Resource_ImplBase.initialize(Resource_ImplBase.java:166)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AnalysisEngineImplBase.initialize(AnalysisEngineImplBase.java:157)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(PrimitiveAnalysisEngine_impl.java:131)
    at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94)
    at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62)
    at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279)
    at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:407)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.asb.impl.ASB_impl.setup(ASB_impl.java:256)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initASB(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:430)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initializeAggregateAnalysisEngine(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:374)
    at org.apache.uima.analysis_engine.impl.AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.initialize(AggregateAnalysisEngine_impl.java:187)
    at org.apache.uima.impl.AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.produceResource(AnalysisEngineFactory_impl.java:94)
    at org.apache.uima.impl.CompositeResourceFactory_impl.produceResource(CompositeResourceFactory_impl.java:62)
    at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceResource(UIMAFramework.java:279)
    at org.apache.uima.UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(UIMAFramework.java:371)
    at org.apache.uima.tools.docanalyzer.DocumentAnalyzer.runProcessingThread(DocumentAnalyzer.java:1223)
    at org.apache.uima.tools.docanalyzer.DocumentAnalyzer$ProcessingThread.run(DocumentAnalyzer.java:1332)
Caused by: org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceConfigurationException: EXCEPTION MESSAGE LOCALIZATION FAILED: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.uima.resource.impl.ConfigurationManagerImplBase.validateConfigurationParameterSettings(ConfigurationManagerImplBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.uima.resource.impl.ConfigurationManagerImplBase.validateConfigurationParameterSettings(ConfigurationManagerImplBase.java:495)
    at org.apache.uima.resource.impl.ConfigurationManagerImplBase.createContext(ConfigurationManagerImplBase.java:169)
    at org.apache.uima.resource.Resource_ImplBase.initialize(Resource_ImplBase.java:162)

Comment: You could try setting your system language to English if that is not already the case. Otherwise, is there a full stack trace that you could post?

Comment: My System language is English. I am unable to post the stack trace because it exceeds the limit of characters i can use to comment.

Comment: Edit your question to post the stack trace - do not put it into the comment.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, UIMA appears to be unable to locate the resource file that contains the error messages or does not find the error message it is looking for within. Which version of UIMA are you using? Did you build it yourself or did you download it from the Apache UIMA website (https://uima.apache.org/downloads.cgi)?

Comment: Currently i am using uima 2.7.0. I have made this annotator by myself and wanted to execute it using Document Analyzer GUI.

Comment: Ok. I don't see any class that you might have created in the stack trace, so my guess would be that there is a problem with the localization in UIMA - or the trace might be incomplete. It looks like there might a problem with the XML descriptor for your annotator and UIMA chokes on internationalization while trying to produce an error message. Can you confirm that the trace is complete? The problem that appears to be swallowed is that a mandatory parameter is not set. Please check that all mandatory parameters have values in your XML descriptor.

Comment: I have not created the XML Descriptor for my Annotator by myself because i am using UIMAFit and i used toXML() method instead.So, the descriptor is automatically generated.

Comment: Ok. So please make sure that you set all the mandatory parameters of your component when you create it with uimaFIT. It might help if you could put the generated XML descriptor somewhere for inspection - posting into the question might not be suitable depending on how large it is.